# Foursquare difference between startAt/endAt and date

Tags: foursquare

I was looking through the Foursquare API about Venue Events and found out that there is a difference between the documentation and the actual response.

In the documentation (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/event), it says that there can be fields such as startAt and endAt in the response. It doesn't mention a field called date.

However, when you go to the expolorer (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/40afe980f964a5203bf31ee3/events), you can see that there is a field called date which contains the seconds from Unix epoch.

Is it because the allDay field is set to true?

Regards,
Norbert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for bringing up this inconsistency in the docs—the `date` field is there for an all-day event. We'll add this to the documentation.